# file-based or database-based caching

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I am developing a site with codeigniter and would like to know which caching system will be best to use with a very large database (above 100k records with many join queries ) so my questions is:

is file-based caching is good or I will have some I/O issues?
or should I write a new driver (I am not sure if codeignter have such driver ) for caching which will store cache in database as key,value pairs?

I cant use memcache or APC due to large size of rows so which should i choose file-based or database-based.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than the row count, it depends on the total data size.

If the total size of the object is less than 1MB then memcache is a better option. But if it going to be more, then you can consider file based cache.

But remember file based cache will always have latency because of disk I/O

**Edit**:

If you cache size is more, then I would recommend File based cache.

Comment: I cant use memcache or APC due to large size of rows so which should i choose file-based or database-based.

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: Thanks again Sudar, but is not there file limit restriction for a directory in linux system as cache directory will contain above 100k files and will it not slow down site performance ?

Comment: I thought you are going to store the search result in a single file. Are you planning to store each record in a sperate file? The performance is inversely proportional to number of files.